# Como visualizar valores seleccionados de mi checkbox en el primer valor

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, dropdown

Estoy un búsqueda de una solución para poder visualizar los elementos que seleccione en mi dropdown en el primer valor, es decir, tengo un dropdown con un listado de valores en checkbox los cuales quisiera visualizar en el primer apartado de mi dropdown sin tener que desplegar todo el listado.

El siguiente es un ejemplo del dropdown con checkbox que estoy implementando:

```js
$(".checkbox-dropdown").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
});

$(".checkbox-dropdown ul").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.checkbox-dropdown {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    user-select: none;
}

/* Display CSS arrow to the right of the dropdown text */
.checkbox-dropdown:after {
    content:'';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #000;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

/* Reverse the CSS arrow when the dropdown is active */
.checkbox-dropdown.is-active:after {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    margin-top: -9px;
}

.checkbox-dropdown-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* align the dropdown right below the dropdown text */
    border: inherit;
    border-top: none;
    left: -1px; /* align the dropdown to the left */
    right: -1px; /* align the dropdown to the right */
  opacity: 0; /* hide the dropdown */
   
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    pointer-events: none; /* avoid mouse click events inside the dropdown */
}
.is-active .checkbox-dropdown-list {
    opacity: 1; /* display the dropdown */
    pointer-events: auto; /* make sure that the user still can select checkboxes */
}

.checkbox-dropdown-list li label {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 10px;
   
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.checkbox-dropdown-list li label:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-dropdown">
  Seleccione una opción
  <ul class="checkbox-dropdown-list">
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Vejle" name="city" />Milwaukee</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Horsens" name="city" />Denver</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Kolding" name="city" />Boston</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Kolding" name="city" />LA</label>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Nuevamente lo explico, lo que requiero es visualizar los elementos seleccionados de mi dropdown en el primer valor, es decir que se puedan visualizar donde esta el valor de `"Seleccione una opción"`.

Espero que alguien pueda entender lo que estoy buscando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema:

> Nuevamente lo explico, lo que requiero es visualizar los elementos seleccionados de mi dropdown en el primer valor, es decir que se puedan visualizar donde esta el valor de "Seleccione una opción".

Solución: Agrega un evento [`onChange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) en tus elementos de tipo `checkbox` para que al ser seleccionados se ejecute un proceso de recolección de elementos seleccionados para después sustituir dinámicamente en el texto que dice `Seleccione una opción`

Es necesario ocupar el atributo de manipulación  [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) de jQuery, crear un [array en javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) y ocupar los atributos de manipulación [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
$(".checkbox-dropdown").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
});

$(".checkbox-dropdown ul").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(ev) {
  let elementos_seleccionados = []
  // ejecutamos este proceso para saber cuáles están seleccionados e irlos guardando dinámicamente en una lista 
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    console.log("estoy seleccionado")
    elementos_seleccionados.push( $(this).val() );
  });
  // finalmente sustituimos todo lo que esté dentro del elemento con la clase .texto-dinamico por todos los elementos seleccionados en el dropdown
  $('.texto-dinamico').html( elementos_seleccionados.join(',') )
  
  // la siguiente condición nos sirve para que en caso de que ningún elemento de la lista sea seleccionado, regrese a su estado original de "Seleccione una opción"
  if ( elementos_seleccionados.length <= 0 ) 
    $('.texto-dinamico').html( 'Seleccione una opción' )
  
  console.log(elementos_seleccionados)
})
```

```css
.checkbox-dropdown {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    user-select: none;
}

/* Display CSS arrow to the right of the dropdown text */
.checkbox-dropdown:after {
    content:'';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #000;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

/* Reverse the CSS arrow when the dropdown is active */
.checkbox-dropdown.is-active:after {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    margin-top: -9px;
}

.checkbox-dropdown-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* align the dropdown right below the dropdown text */
    border: inherit;
    border-top: none;
    left: -1px; /* align the dropdown to the left */
    right: -1px; /* align the dropdown to the right */
  opacity: 0; /* hide the dropdown */
   
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    pointer-events: none; /* avoid mouse click events inside the dropdown */
}
.is-active .checkbox-dropdown-list {
    opacity: 1; /* display the dropdown */
    pointer-events: auto; /* make sure that the user still can select checkboxes */
}

.checkbox-dropdown-list li label {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 10px;
   
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.checkbox-dropdown-list li label:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-dropdown">
  <div class="texto-dinamico">Seleccione una opción</div>
  <ul class="checkbox-dropdown-list">
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Vejle" name="city" />Milwaukee</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Horsens" name="city" />Denver</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Kolding" name="city" />Boston</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Kolding" name="city" />LA</label>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta parece funcionar, pero en mi caso no lo puedo hacer con el parametro del input `value` ya que allí lo tendré que usar para guardar, hay posibilidad de hacerlo con el parametro del input `name` o `id` remplazando `.val()` por algún otro en JQuery ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Así es, en lugar de ocupar `$(this).val()` recoge el valor que tenga, por ejemplo, el atributo name como `$(this).attr('name')`. Es decir, sería en lugar de esto `elementos_seleccionados.push( $(this).val() );` esto `elementos_seleccionados.push( $(this).attr('name') );`

Comment: Excelente respuesta clara y concisa

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer que los elementos seleccionados se muestren en el espacio donde dice "Seleccione una opción", pero necesitas crear un nuevo contenedor para el mensaje y la lista de elementos que se hayan seleccionado, mostrando solo uno u otro.

También se necesitan algunas reglas CSS adicionales para saber cómo mostrar la lista de elementos seleccionados.

```js
// Span con mensaje
let selSpan = $(".checkbox-dropdown > div > span");
// Lista de elementos seleccionados
let selList = $(".checkbox-dropdown > div > ul");
// Lista de opciones (todavía no seleccionadas)
let selOptions = $(".checkbox-dropdown > ul");

$(".checkbox-dropdown").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
});

/* Esta función sirve para ambas listas */
$(".checkbox-dropdown ul > li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Obtener checkbox
    let chk = $(e.currentTarget).find('input');
    if(chk.is(':checked')) {
        // Está marcado, mover a lista de seleccionados
        selList.append(e.currentTarget);
    } else {
        // Está desmarcado, mover a lista normal
        selOptions.append(e.currentTarget);
    }
    // Mostrar u ocultar texto, dependiendo de si hay algo seleccionado o no
    if(selList.children('li').length == 0) {
        // No hay elementos seleccionados, mostrar mensaje
        selSpan.css('display', 'inline-block');
    } else {
        // Al menos hay un elemento seleccionado, ocultar mensaje
        selSpan.css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

```css
.checkbox-dropdown {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    user-select: none;
}
/* Lista de elementos seleccionados */
.checkbox-dropdown > div > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.checkbox-dropdown > div > ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #44a;
    background: #aef;
    border: 1px #44a solid;
    margin: 2px 5px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
/* Ocultar checkbox de elementos seleccionados */
.checkbox-dropdown > div > ul li input { display: none; }
/* Cambiar color cuando pase el mouse */
.checkbox-dropdown > div > ul li:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #44a;
    border: 1px #008 solid;
}

/* Display CSS arrow to the right of the dropdown text */
.checkbox-dropdown:after {
    content:'';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #000;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}

/* Reverse the CSS arrow when the dropdown is active */
.checkbox-dropdown.is-active:after {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    margin-top: -9px;
}

.checkbox-dropdown-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* align the dropdown right below the dropdown text */
    border: inherit;
    border-top: none;
    left: -1px; /* align the dropdown to the left */
    right: -1px; /* align the dropdown to the right */
  opacity: 0; /* hide the dropdown */
   
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    pointer-events: none; /* avoid mouse click events inside the dropdown */
}
.is-active .checkbox-dropdown-list {
    opacity: 1; /* display the dropdown */
    pointer-events: auto; /* make sure that the user still can select checkboxes */
}

.checkbox-dropdown-list li label {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 10px;
   
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.checkbox-dropdown-list li label:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-dropdown">
  <!-- Crear contenedores para texto y lista de seleccionados -->
  <div><span>Seleccione una opción</span><ul></ul></div>
  <ul class="checkbox-dropdown-list">
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Vejle" name="city">Milwaukee</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Horsens" name="city">Denver</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Kolding" name="city">Boston</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Kolding" name="city">LA</label>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```